# ADFS: Send user manager's email address as a claim

Tags: adfs, windows-server

I integrated SSO with ADFS, and I need to get the manager's email of whoever is currently logging in. When I send over the manager attribute using:

```
query = ";manager;{0}"
```

I only get back the manager name and org.

I tried following this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ff678048(v=ws.10)

However, the rules given in the example result in a syntax error.

and tried various methods from threads such as: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/903e217b-a441-41d6-9400-661644820500/extract-manager-email-address?forum=Geneva

I think I need to query for the manager using their name somehow, but I am having trouble coming up with a solution. I do understand I likely need multiple rules. Can anyone shed some light on this problem? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following rule illustrates how you can issue a mail attribute as a “ManagerEmail” claim:

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname"]
&& c1:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/ManagerDistinguishedName"]
=> issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/ManagerEmail"), query = "(&(distinguishedName={0})(objectClass=user));mail;{1}", param = c1.Value, 
param = regexreplace(c1.Value, ".*DC=(?<domain>.+),DC=corp,DC=yourdomain,DC=com", "${domain}\username"));
```

Make sure that the user’s manager is in the same domain as the user, i.e. *corp.yourdomain.com* in the above example, and your test user does have some email specified.

Comment: Hey Kate, thanks! Unfortunately the SAML response comes back with no manager email. I may be doing something wrong, especially since I am completely new to MS server. I also tried changing DC=corp,DC=yourdomain,DC=com to the output from nltest /dclist:domain, to no avail.